# How can i set current date using expression builder in oracle adf?

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

How can i set current date using expression builder in oracle adf?
i am using jdeveloper 11.1.1.3.0 and using Input Date(ADF faces.common.component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression builder is used to build EL expressions that reference a method or a value property. Its not meant to set a value but to make it available for editing. One option would be to use a method expression to invoke an action on a manage bean that then sets the value. However, in JSF 1.2 you cannot pass arguments to an EL method and for this reason you would need a work around for setting a date. The work around is that the method expression (and thus the press of a button) invokes a method, which then creates the current date (or whatever date you want to pass in) and sets it on the component directly (though setting it on the component model works much better IMO).

Frank

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to have your datasource field have a default value defined for it in the business service layer. So for example if you are using ADF BC then your field can have a default of adf.currentDate.

Comment: this will effect the datasource on changing dates.I did it using managed bean.thanx