# what type of language can be typed in oracle adf expression builder

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to do two things, but I am little bit confused:

1. I am trying in jdeveloper to reference the sysdate in the value of output text through the expression builder, and used adf.currentDate, but didn't work.
2. I don't know when to use the expression builder and what language I should type to reference either `dataModel` attribute or UI component functions? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`adf.currentDate` must not be added in expression builder, it is groovy language. You can add it in the Default Value in the Model Layer.

Go to **EntityObject.xml file -> Attributes -> double click on your attribute -> write `adf.currentDate`** in the Value field.

This is the Default value given to the attribute

For your second question, i would prefer you look at this below link

[How can i set current date using expression builder in oracle adf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503249/how-can-i-set-current-date-using-expression-builder-in-oracle-adf)